# Existence of the function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$ Given \ f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto [-1,1] $$
a function differentiable up to the second order and satisfying the following relation:
$$ (f(0))^2+(f'(0))^2=4 \tag{1} $$
Is it true that if f satisfies equation (1) then there must be a c∈$\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies equation (2)?
$$ f(c)+f''(c)=0 \tag{2} $$

I tried to solve this problem by trying to solve the equation 2, but I had problems to limit the domain.

I'd like to solve this problem without using the theory of differential equations, but I have no idea of how to do that.

Comment: Try $y=\sin(ax)$ and try to find a value of $a$ that works.

Comment: In the problem, I'd like to show that this is always true or find a counterexample. With this approach, I don't show what I want, do I?

Comment: By "always true" do you mean for any value of $c$?

Comment: No, I mean: Is always there a function f that satisfies that problem? 
In this problem the main issue is about the existence of the function, I guess I hadn't made a good translation, sorry!

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? What value of $a$ works for equation (1)? Using that value of $a$ is there a $c$ that works for equation (2)? How many?

Comment: In my first attempt to solve that problem, I used the function y=sin(2x)... This function satisfies the problem.
Although I couldn't show that any function that satisfies the equation (1) will satisfy the equation to for some value of c in the domain.

Comment: Then $c$ can equal any value of $x$ for which $\sin(2x)=0$. There are infinitely many in $\mathbb{R}$ but only one in the given domain.

Comment: This argument does not guarantee that every function that satisfies the property (1) will satisfy the property (2). This is just an exemple of function that satisfies the problem

Comment: OK, now I understand what you wish to ask. Edit your second sentence: "Will always have a function that satisfies this equation for a given c in domain?" to say  instead "Is it true that if $f$ satisfies equation (1) then there must be a $c$ which satisfies equation (2)?

Comment: Done, thank you for the help and patience

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question, but now the question is clearly stated so that perhaps someone else knows how to help.

Comment: That's fine, thank you any way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argue by contradiction. Replace $f$ by $-f$ if necessary, we assume $f+f''>0$ everywhere.  Replace $f$ by $f(-x)$ if necessary, we can assume $f'(0)>0$. Actually $f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=4$ and $f$ ranges in $[-1, 1]$ implies $|f'(0)|\geq \sqrt 3$; in particular $f'(0)\geq \sqrt 3$. 
Now observe 
$$
[f^2+(f')^2]'=2f(x)f'(x)+2f'(x)f''(x)=2f'(x)[f(x)+f''(x)].
$$
Let $T$ be the biggest number so that $f'\geq 1$ on $[0, T]$, we see $f^2+(f')^2$ is increasing on $[0, T]$, so $f^2+(f')^2>4$ at $T$, which then implies $f'(T)>\sqrt 3$, thus 
$f'>1$ on some $[0, T+\delta]$. This implies actually $T=\infty$. Now $f'>1$ on $[0, \infty)$ and this makes $f$ not bounded from above, contradicts the fact $f$ ranges in $[-1, 1]$.

This argument should work if you replace $4$ by any number $>1$.